# EPS file not displaying correctly when exported from InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, export, eps

I am working on a directory document that was created using InDesign CS6. It has three .eps files of map regions which were originally created in Illustrator CS6 that have been imported into the file. For some reason when I export the document, the map .eps files do not display correctly. I have created and exported many InDesign documents with linked .eps files before and have never seen this happen. Does this issue stem from InDesign, or the .eps file itself? How do I fix this so the maps display correctly when exported? This will be  printed as a small book. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**What the exported file should look like:**
[image: What the exported file should look like]

**How it is currently displaying when exported:**
[image: How it is currently displaying when exported]

Comment: My gut says you have a clipping path or alpha channel in there somewhere. Maybe to test, you can place a colored box under the map and see if the white lines take on the color of the box. etc

Comment: Did you place a TIFF in Illustrator and then overlay vector on it and then export EPS?

Comment: No, all of the roads are separate layers from another Illustrator file that I placed on top of my state outline. It looks like the problem was saving it as .eps, it exported perfectly once I resaved those files to .ai. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried saving it as a ".ai" or ".pdf" file and re-importing it into ID?  Also, what are you exporting as?

Comment: I'm exporting it as a pdf. It looks like your suggestion worked - I resaved the map files as .ai and reimported them into InDesign, and now they're displaying correctly once I've exported to pdf. I feel a bit embarrassed I didn't think to try that first! Thanks!

Comment: Don't even worry about it. I'm glad it worked out. I'm from the old school of using ".eps" files all the time, but have learned to phase them in favor of ".ai" and/or ".pdf". Since ".eps" is now considered an old format that is being used and less and less.